# How can I extract a value from a dataframe based on a range of values?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data:

```
library(tidyverse)

table <- tibble(
  points = 0:10,
  energy = c(0, 120, 240, 300, 380, 500, 600, 780, NA, NA, NA),
  cost = c(0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0)
)
```

I am trying to write a function that takes a value as an argument, measures it against the values in `energy` and then returns an associated `points` value.

So far I can understand a basic mechanism for extracting this along the lines of:

```
energy_points <- function(energy_input) {
table_one %>%
  filter(energy == energy_input) %>%
  pull(points)
}
```

However the intended operation of my function is that it looks at the energy_input value and checks which "range" it falls into before assigning a score.

So a value of 125 is greater than 120 and less than 241, so returns a points of 1. A value of 120 is not greater than 120 so returns a points of 0. Some more expected outputs if helpful:

| energy_input | points |
| --- | --- |
| 50 | 0 |
| 120 | 0 |
| 121 | 1 |
| 240 | 1 |
| 241 | 2 |

**How can I write the function so it checks ranges based on values in the table?**

Comment: What if the input is >780?

Comment: @zephryl if the input is > 780, it should return 7 points (for the purpose of what I am building this is the max possible score). Thanks for picking that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can index by the last element of `energy` that’s < the input:

```r
energy_points <- function(energy_input) {
  # assumes `table` is sorted in ascending order by `energy`
  with(
    table, 
    points[[max(which(energy < energy_input))]]
  )
}

# test
input <- c(50, 120, 121, 240, 241, 780, 781)

data.frame(input, output = sapply(input, energy_points))
#   input output
# 1    50      0
# 2   120      0
# 3   121      1
# 4   240      1
# 5   241      2
# 6   780      6
# 7   781      7
```

Or, for a tidyverse solution similar to your initial approach:

```r
library(dplyr)

energy_points <- function(energy_input) {
  table %>%
    filter(energy < energy_input) %>%
    slice_max(energy) %>%
    pull(points)
}
```